# Topology and mapping of boundary points

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $\Omega$ is a set of points in the xy plane, and f is a continuous transformation from points in the xy plane to points in the xy plane.

What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for this:

$f(\partial\Omega)\subset \partial(f (\Omega))$

ie: boundary points map to boundary points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that by "$\subset$", you mean "$\subseteq$".

We have
$$
f(\partial \Omega) \subseteq \partial f(\Omega)
\iff
f(\partial \Omega) \subseteq \text{cl } f(\Omega)
\land
f(\partial \Omega) \cap \text{int } f(\Omega) = \emptyset
$$

Because $f$ is continuous, we have $f(\text{cl } \Omega) \subseteq \text{cl } f(\Omega)$, so

$$
f(\partial \Omega) \subseteq \partial f(\Omega)
\iff
f(\partial \Omega) \cap \text{int } f(\Omega) = \emptyset
\\ \iff
(\forall x \in \text{cl } \Omega : f(x) \in \text{int } f(\Omega) \implies x \in \text{int } \Omega)
\\ \iff
\text{cl } \Omega \cap f^{-1}(\text{int } f(\Omega)) \subseteq \text{int } \Omega
$$

(If any of the steps are unclear, please ask me!)

Now I can't simplify this any further (does anybody else have an idea?).
Also, I could only think of one sufficient condition:

- If $f$ is injective, your condition holds, since we have $f^{-1}(f(\Omega)) = \Omega$, but since $f$ is continuous, the preimage is also open, so $f^{-1}(\text{int } f(\Omega)) \subseteq \text{int } \Omega$.